# Flutter window_utils not compiling code and giving CMakeLists.txt file error

Tags: flutter, plugins, flutter-desktop

I am using window_utils flutter plugin in my flutter desktop application. When I run my app I got this error [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjytN.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjytN.png).

This is my pubspec.yaml code [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIQOB.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIQOB.png).

https://pub.dev/documentation/window_utils/latest/

I tried all versions of this plugin but not working. Can anyone help me what is the issue and how to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that that plugin was written against a very early pre-release version of Flutter's desktop support, before the plugin build system and APIs were at all stabilized. Unfortunately it was published despite the clear warning against doing so at the time, and then, predictably, stopped working very shortly thereafter when the next breaking change happened. Since it was not updated after that point, it has never worked since.

There is no way to resolve it other than either forking it and rewriting it for the final version of the plugin system (including completely replacing its build system), or using a different plugin.

Comment: Is there any other way round? Was using this plugin to hide title bar of window.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I am working on flutter desktop application and using this plugin (mentioned above) to hide title bar of window. How can I achieve this?

Comment: My last paragraph already answered that question.

Answer (score 0):

Although the plugin is out of date, the C++ code for Windows can still work.

You can find the source code at `pub.dartlang.org\window_utils-1.0.2\windows`.

[image]

Create a new plugin project with the latest Flutter SDK by yourself:

```
flutter create --template=plugin --platforms=windows test
```

Define a Flutter method in `lib.dart`:

```dart
static Future<void> hideTitleBar() async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('hideTitleBar');
  }
```

Add the C++ code to *.cpp file:

```cpp
void FlutterBarcodeSdkPlugin::HandleMethodCall(
      const flutter::MethodCall<flutter::EncodableValue> &method_call,
      std::unique_ptr<flutter::MethodResult<flutter::EncodableValue>> result)
  {

    if (method_call.method_name().compare("hideTitleBar") == 0)
    {
      HWND hWnd = GetActiveWindow();
      SetMenu(hWnd, NULL);
      LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
      // lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU);
      // lStyle &= WS_DLGFRAME;
      lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU | WS_DLGFRAME);
      SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);
      LONG flags = SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER;
      SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, flags);
      flutter::EncodableValue response(true);
      result->Success(&response);
    }
}
```

I've tested it in my app.

Before hiding the title bar:

[image]

After hiding the title bar:

[image]